# Command That Clears Python Console?

Tags: python, python-3.5

Python 3.5.0

I'm working with 150-200 lines of code so it isn't the worst. But this game involves a lot of repetitive lines of code, so I was wondering if there was a command that clears the whole console (for instance if I was to write code that prints "hello world" then it clears itself and prints "hello usa" where "hello world" used to be) before outputting the next line of code. I'm hoping to do this in the code editor in IDLE instead of the shell.

I guess I didn't make it clear enough D: sorry, my bad. I tried the import os way, and it just opened up a cmd console every once and a while for about a fraction of a second. I want a command that I can write in the python code editor that comes with idle, so that whenever I run the program and the program pops up, the text will pop up on the running program, disappear, then print the next text (or next step of the program).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, You will have to import os of course, and i am hoping you are using windows

```
>>> import os
>>> clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
>>> clear()
```

in linux you can try

```
os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 0):

On *nix you could say,

```
os.system("clear")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming windows, try:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```